# It is only displaying delete message in second row only

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code where it is displaying the delete message '`$(".imagemsg" + counter).html(data);`'. But it is displaying the delete message after a file has been deleted in the second row only, this is incorrect, it should only be displayed in the row the file was deleted from.

For example, if the file was deleted from the 3rd row, the message should be displayed in the 3rd row, if file was deleted from 6th row, it should display delete message in 6th row and etc. But at the moment no matter which row the file is deleted from, only the second row displays the delete message.

```
   var counter = 0;

function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){

      var result = '';
      counter++;

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="imagemsg'+counter+'">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';      
         $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>'); 
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="imageemsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }


      $(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {

         var image_file_name = $(this).attr('image_file_name');

    jQuery.ajax("deleteimage.php?imagefilename=" + image_file_name)
      .done(function(data) {
        $(".imagemsg" + counter).html(data);
       });

       $(this).parent().remove();

    });

      return true;   
}
```

The result variable is called here in the imageupload.php:

CALLBACK:

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>, '<?php echo $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] ?>');</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is not ideal overall.  A better approach would probably be to give them all the same class and then use things like `parent`, `find`, `children` etc. to find the appropriate elements.

However, without massively overhauling your code, i thin this should fix it:

```
var _counter = counter;

$('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).find(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {
    var image_file_name = $(this).attr('image_file_name');

    jQuery.ajax("deleteimage.php?imagefilename=" + image_file_name)
        .done(function(data) {

        $(".imagemsg" + _counter).html(data);
    });

    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Basically the click handler is only attached to the appropriate button and the appropriate `counter` value is used.

Comment: I have tried your method but it is still causing the same problem. Here is the link to the app [here](https://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable3.php). When you open app, if you click on the "Add" button twice, and then upload a file in the first row's file input, it will display the file name at bottom of first row. Then in second row's file input upload a different file, you will see the file name of that file at the bottom of the second row. But when you delete both files, the message (file was Deleted) is still only displayed in second row only. Hope this helps :)